# I've finished my studies and currently looking for a job?

Tags: grammaticality, formality, writing-style, register, contemporary-english

I'm writing my first CV (resume) before applying for some jobs.

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> I've finished my studies and currently looking for a job

Comment: not judging by the grammar or english , i dont think this line goes anywhere in your resume for job application

Comment: I would rather imply or emphasise that my studies are concluded and that I am willing to commit my time to my new employer by saying something like: "I have concluded my studies recently and am seeking for a suitable employment at a reputable company"

Comment: It is best to avoid contractions, abbreviations and colloquial expressions in a resume. Your CV should be written in a formal style, if the company you are applying to is young, and positively encourages a relaxed easy-going attitude then this can be reflected in your cover letter (but I would only recommend this to native speakers.) Hence: "I have recently finished my studies and I am currently seeking employment"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll address the grammar involved rather than the tone / style (which isn't really an appropriate topic on this site – you need to look elsewhere for that sort of guidance).

> "I've finished my studies and I've moved back to Brighton."

is fine grammatically (but rather too informal in style for a CV). It is a compound sentence.
It may be shortened to

> "I've finished my studies and moved back to Brighton."

......

> "I've finished my studies and I have been looking for a job."

is again fine (if informal), but would not usually be ellipted to

> "I've finished my studies and been looking for a job."

(Though the second 'I' can be ellipted.)

......

> "I've finished my studies and I'm currently looking for a job."

is fine, but uses **two different auxiliaries** (have / 've and am / 'm) and can only undergo ellipsis to this stage:

> "I've finished my studies and am currently looking for a job."

Comment: Ill personally go with the last one. What exactly though is wrong with :: ' I've finished my studies and currently, looking for a job' besides that it feels like missing an 'am'.

Comment: That's the point. But the new comma isn't good.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly correct English, except that you need to include 'am' either before 'currently' or before 'looking'.

'I've finished my studies and am currently looking for a job'.